How to deploy files along with the current application in a portable way with Qt CMake build?
I have two big files I want to pack/deploy with my application. On desktop, that would be as easy as copying them to deployment archive, but I am also targeting Android. I don't want to make these files a QResource for two reasons:

One of them is 250MB, I don't think file that big belongs inside the binary
I really want them to be on filesystem on Desktop platforms

I want to set things up so that by default when I deploy the app, I'll have a reliable filesystem path to find the files at. Ideally applicationDirPath() + myFilename.
How can I tell Qt that certain files in the project dir belong with my application executable?

At least when publishing to Google Play, one can utilize asset delivery.
You'd have to build eg. one product flavor for desktop and one for mobile.
Or in other terms, one fully featured package and one split AAB.
Generally speaking, the Play Core Native SDK has to be added to the native side
and the playcore-native-metadata.jar on the Java side tells it what/how to fetch.

I afraid this is kinda opposite of what I want - a cross platform solution, even if not the most elegant one. I don't think I'll ever publish the app in google play anyways.

Qt would support this by default: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#external-binary-resources
